# How do I access a dataframe value only if a certain column exists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains, yfinance

How do I make it so that if there is no term 'Short Long Term Debt' in the dataframe then `short_long_term_debt = 0`, but if there is then use the final line?

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import requests
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 150)
ticker = yf.Ticker("ATVI")


financials = ticker.financials.T
balance = ticker.balance_sheet.T

interest_expense = financials['Interest Expense']['2020'].iloc[0]

if not balance['Short Long Term Debt']: 
  short_long_term_debt = 0
  short_long_term_debt = balance['Short Long Term Debt']['2020'].iloc[0]
```

---

Currently this code gives the following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Short Long Term Debt'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'Short Long Term Debt'
```

Comment: you frame `balance` does not have a column called `Short Long Term Debt`

Comment: Yes I know but depending on the ticker that I put into: ticker = yf.Ticker("ATVI") will slightly change the dataframe. Some dataframes do have the term Short Long Term Debt. I want to write a code so that on the chance that the term Short Long Term Debt is not included in the data frame is assigns the value 0 to short_long_term_debt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if `Short Long Term Debt` is in `balance.columns`:

```py
if 'Short Long Term Debt' in balance.columns:
    short_long_term_debt = balance['Short Long Term Debt']['2020'].iloc[0]
else:
    short_long_term_debt = 0
```

Comment: Thank you this worked it's exactly what I was looking for!